# REST "dry-run" option for PUT or POST

Tags: rest

Is there an idiomatic way of achieving this:

I need to PUT/POST a given entity. However, before actually putting it I need to do some changes on a more volatile system, and if that works I will go on.

So I will first ask if the PUT/POST is acceptable and then later actually do the PUT/POST.

I've thought of just using a "dry-run" query-parameter, but it doesn't feel like the right way.

**Update**: Trying to clarify my problem. The point is that the first PUT is just for verification of the entity.

```
Me           System A       Volatile System X
|    Dry PUT    |                    :
|-------------->|                    :
|               |                    :
|   20x / 40x   |                    :
|<--------------|                    :
|               :                    :
| Upon PUT OK do some related work   :
|----------------------------------->|
|               :                    |
| Work completely                    |
|<-----------------------------------|
|               :
|PUT (for real) :
|-------------->|
|               |
|     20x       |
|<--------------|
```

Comment: I guess "the right way" is to just do a full blown PUT and the server should return some 4xx error if the PUT is unacceptable.

Comment: Problem is; if it goes through it will be saved before the other system is changed; which may not go through, leaving the systems in conflicting state.

Comment: Then it shouldn't "go through", it should return a 4xx error code.

Answer (score 4):

Logically I feel that this could perhaps be solved by a some kind of state property. If you are using JSON, you might for example consider adding a property like this:

```
{
  "draft" : true
}
```

The first time you do the PUT request, you mark the item as draft. It stores the item but doesn't do anything else with it .

After your server accepted your request, you can then do your 'related work' elsewhere, and if that succeeded as well you can submit another PUT request to the same resource, this time setting `draft` to `false`.

Comment: If its the same resource, the second request would be a PATCH right? Otherwise, it would be a PUT to "originalResource/draft"

Comment: PUT is used to _replace_ a resource, so you can definitely use `PUT` again on the same resource. `PATCH` is only usually used if you want to do a partial replace of the resource.

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to set `draft` to `false` in this case though?